# How to debug quarkus lambda locally

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus, quarkus-native

I am beginner to Quarkus lambda and when I am looking for how to debug the Quarkus lambda then everyone is showing with REST API endpoints, is there any way to debug the Quarkus app using lambda handler ?

I know how to start the app in dev mode but I am struggling with invoking the handler method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SAM CLI for local debugging and testing. [Here](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda-http#simulate-amazon-lambda-deployment-with-sam-cli) is the official documentation from quarkus.

It's really important that you follow the sequence.

**Step-1:**

> sam local start-api --template target/sam.jvm.yaml -d 5005

**Step-2:**

> Hit your API using your favourite rest client

**Step-3**

> Add a Remote JVM debug configuration in your IDE, set your breakpoints and start debugging.

[image: Remote JVM debugging]

Comment: An example template.yml can be found under target folder after building your Quarkus project once

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just add a Main class and set up a usual Run Configuration.

```java
 import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.QuarkusMain;
 import io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus;

 @QuarkusMain
 public class Main {
   public static void main(String ... args) {
       System.out.println("Running main method");
       Quarkus.run(args);
    }
 }
```

After that, just use curl or Postman to invoke the endpoint.
By default, the lambda handler starts on port 8080.
You can override it by passing

```
-Dquarkus.lambda.mock-event-server.dev-port=9999
```

So the curl will look like:

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9999/hello"
```

if the definition of the resource class looks like:

```java
    @Path("/hello")
    public class GreetingResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String hello() {
        return "hello jaxrs";
      }
    }
```

Add a breakpoint in the Resource class and start the Main class in Debug mode. This will actually pause during a debug on a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run `mvn quarkus:dev` and connect a remote debugger to it on port 5005 as shown in this image

[image]

Once quarkus is started in dev mode and you connect the remote debugger you can use Postman to send a request. Your breakpoints will be evaluated.